java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3944 byte allocation with 104656 free bytes and 102KB until OOM, target footprint
I am getting an issue while application is running. App crash after some time.
Here is log of crashing…
E/AndroidRuntime(15295): FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Loader:ProgressiveMediaPeriod
E/AndroidRuntime(15295): Process: com.app.dubfeed, PID: 15295
E/AndroidRuntime(15295): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3944 byte allocation with 104656 free bytes and 102KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3578)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:638)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2843)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Log.appendThrowableString(Log.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Log.e(Log.java:254)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:440)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime(15295):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Here is my manifest file code:-
<application
        android:label=""
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">

I already added android.hardwareAccelerated and android.largeHeap.
Still getting crash. So is there any way to fix this issue.
Here is code of VideoPlayer which is used for feed video...
   class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initVideoPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.play != widget.play) {
      if (_chewieController != null) {
        if (widget.play) {
          _chewieController!.play();
        } else {
          _chewieController!.pause();
          _clearCacheIfNeeded();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    try {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.url));
      await _controller.initialize();
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _controller,
        autoInitialize: true,
        autoPlay: widget.play,
        looping: true,
        allowFullScreen: false,
        showControls: false,
        placeholder: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );

      setState(() {});
      print("Controller initialized");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error initializing video: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    _clearCacheIfNeeded();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _clearCacheIfNeeded() {
    if (!widget.play) {
      final cacheManager = DefaultCacheManager();
      cacheManager.emptyCache().then((value) {
        print("Cache cleared");
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.hasError
        ? Center(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriLarge,
              errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriSmall,
                errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Center(
                  child: Text("Temporary video is not available"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController!,
                ),
              )
            : Center(
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriLarge,
                  errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: widget.thumbnailUriSmall,
                    errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Center(
                      child: Text("Temporary video is not available"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
  }
}

This player handled with InviewNotifire. play variable value comes from InviewNotifireList. so, while play is true, video will play and while play is false, video will false video will pause.

are you allocating any huge video content into memory?

show your exoplayer code.

Hello @pskink, I’m playing video using chewie player at flutter side. And i got multiple videos and photos at a feed. And this error comes, while i am use that feed. Also i clear caches while video pause or dispose.

Hello @Ranjithkumar, I attach my video player code.
